# How to make a FlexBean plugin cooperate with maven flex project

Tags: apache-flex, maven-2, netbeans

I have a flex maven project written by externel company that I need to modify. I dont have a Flash Builder licence yet (it takes forever to buy anythng in my company) .

I installed Netbeans 6.5 and FlexBean but when i opended flex maven project the action script code is ont recognized as action script by the IDE. Ho to make it "flex aware" ?

Answer (score 0):

nb 6.5 is fairly old. does the flexbean integration require such old version?
some 3rd party tools might not integrate with the maven project type in netbeans and only do so with the default ant based projects.. if that's the case I suggest filing an issue against flexbean